# OPCUA Methods in Apache Camel Milo

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, opc-ua, milo

What is the right way to call an opcua method with camel milo?

I keep doing tests but I always get the inputArguments and not the outputArguments even if checking the MILO log messages I see that the method is called and returns the correct value.

Apache Camel version 3.11.1

I thank anyone who can give me a suggestion!!

```
public void test() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("START CAMEL-MILO TEST");
        
        SpringCamelContext camelContext = applicationContext.getBean(SpringCamelContext.class); 
        
        if( camelContext != null )
        {
            ProducerTemplate producerTemplate  = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
            
            if( producerTemplate != null )
            {
                String   endpointUri = "milo-client:opc.tcp://milo.digitalpetri.com:62541/milo?node=RAW(ns=2;s=Methods)&method=RAW(ns=2;s=Methods/sqrt(x))&defaultAwaitWrites=true";
                Double   value       = 25.0;

                 Double outputArguments = producerTemplate.requestBody(endpointUri, new Variant(value),  Double.class);

                if(outputArguments != null)
                    System.out.println("RESULT: " + outputArguments );
                else
                    System.out.println("ERROR: outputArguments is null");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("ERROR: ProducerTemplateunavailable");              
        }
        else
            System.out.println("ERROR: SpringCamelContext unavailable");
    }
```